# Is there a template language for PHP that's almost similar to the Django template language?

Tags: php, django, templates, django-templates

Is there a template language for PHP that's almost similar to the Django template language?

Comment: But *not* being written in PHP is half of what makes Django so great! ;-)

Comment: PHP itself is the best template language for PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called Calypso.
You can find it [here](http://www.beberlei.de/calypso/)!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

- [H2O](http://wiki.github.com/speedmax/h2o-php)
- [Calypso](http://www.beberlei.de/calypso/)

Also, I believe Django's templating engine took a fair amount of inspiration from [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) in the first place.